# Cast generic with base type

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class ViewModel<TNavigationData> : BindableBase
        where TNavigationData : class, new()
{
   //....
}


   public class SomeClass()
   {
      public SomeClass()
      {
      }
   }
```

Somewhere in the code I am trying to cast given view model as a object to concrete generic type. Here what I am doing:

```
protected virtual async Task NavigateImplAsync<TData>(IView view, TData navigationData)
            where TData : class, new()
{
     object viewModelAsObject = GetFromSomewhere() //this is ViewModel<SomeClass>

     //typeof(TData) = SomeClass

     var t4 = viewModelAsObject  as ViewModel<TData>;

     //this cast returns null however TData 

}
```

Why cannot I cast that into ViewModel if viewModelAsObject variable is that class and TData is SomeClass type?

Comment: Are you saying that `viewModelAsObject` is actually `ViewModel<SomeClass>`, and when you try to cast this to `ViewModel<TData>` when `TData` is `SomeClass`, you get back `null`? It would help if you were to create an [mcve] so we don't have to guess.

Comment: To be clear, if `viewModelAsObject` *really* is `ViewModel<SomeClass>`, then it'll work, but if it is `ViewModel<SomethingThatInheritsFromSomeClass>`, then it won't work.

Comment: So I guess the question is this: `TData`, **what is it *really*?**

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen `//typeof(TData) = SomeClass` not sure if that comment is to say TData is in fact SomeClass ?

Comment: As pointed out you really should provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I didn't like that either at first, but in most cases where it is required i figured out my problem while setting up the example. Think of it as your effort based rubber duck fixing issues. The additional benefit is that the "can i be bothered to do it for the OP?"-factor is modified to a great favor towards you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a general example from your shown code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SomeFunc<SomeClass>();
}

private static void SomeFunc<TData>() where TData : class, new()
{
    object gsc = IReturnSomeGenericClassWithSomeClass();

    var check = gsc as GenericClass<TData>;
    System.Console.WriteLine(check == null ? "is null" : "is not null");
}

private static GenericClass<SomeClass> IReturnSomeGenericClassWithSomeClass() { return new GenericClass<SomeClass>(); }

class SomeClass { }
class GenericClass<T> { }
```

This example works fine, I guess there must be an error in your function ViewModelAsObject().

Otherwise please try to map your code to this example or [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: but TData is ClassA and ViewModel<ClssA>

Comment: @miechooy Ah, sry, I misunderstood your problem. I'll see if I can write a correct answer and will then replace this one